# Pagination and sorting not working properly

Tags: php, mysql

I did the pagination for data I'm retrieving from the database. when I'm trying to sort each page separately it's not working. It's like it's ordering the whole chunk of data and spreading it on both pages. I need to sort the contents of each page separately...

Q1:

```
SELECT `firstName`, `lastName`, `creationDate`, `applicationStatus` 
FROM student 
ORDER BY firstName ASC LIMIT 0 , 25
```

Q2:

```
SELECT `firstName`, `lastName`, `creationDate`, `applicationStatus` 
FROM student 
ORDER BY firstName DESC LIMIT 25 , 25
```

Q2 gives me a chunk of Q1's data but in the opposite order of Q1. what I need is the same output of Q2 but sorted in both ways... and it's not happening!

Comment: What does that mean "it's not happening"? What *is* happening? What is the exact question here?

Comment: In case you want to know how you can accept an answer you could read this: [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Comment: `SELECT * FROM ( <Original Query> ) o ORDER BY o.firstName DESC`

Comment: @DaveRandom thnx mate for this tip. you answered my question. It's working fine now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how the ORDER BY clause works.  If you want to sort each page independently, you need to either select it into a temporary table and ORDER BY that, or sort it in your program.

Answer (score 2):

That is because you are reversing your `ORDER BY`. Keep it the same as `Q1`.

```
SELECT `firstName`, `lastName`, `creationDate`, `applicationStatus` 
FROM student 
ORDER BY firstName ASC LIMIT 25 , 25
```

You want to keep your `ORDER BY` the same, as this will ensure that your offset 25 starts where your LIMIT 25 ends.